# GeoServer develop or use? How can I integrate with geoserver?

Tags: java, gis, geoserver, wms

I'm going to develop a map server with my own logic and entities. It will have postgres database, user management, specific layers with certain types, WFS, WMS, etc.
I'm going to use **springframework** and **GeoServer** as the GeoServer is an open source project. My question is whether I develop it or use it as a separated server? How about the user management problem? How can I integrate my own project security with the geoserver?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Geoserver is web map server which runs in a servlet container like tomcat or jetty. Do you want to extend Geoserver or use some components to develop another map server? Or do you want simply develop a web gis or similar?

Comment: I want simply develop a web gis or smaller

Comment: Geoserver is typically used as WMS backend (or TMS or WFS...), completely separated from the client. You don't have to develop it unless you have particular needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you develop a front end that's completely separate and have GeoServer offer the OGC services to it and other clients. In case you need to customize it, GeoServer has a fully pluggable architecture, e.g., you can build a version of it that has more or less modules than the standard one, your own security subsystem, your own custom data sources, and so on, a lot can be either configured or replaced, so I'd suggest you look into those options.

Mind one detail, GeoServer is GPL'd, so any code you develop that depends on GeoServer API will similarly be GPL'd. If instead you develop something that's only based on GeoTools (e.g., a custom data store) that part can be closed source.

Comment: I have this problem too. please see [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150904/can-i-use-web-map-service-module-and-web-feature-service-module-of-geoserver).

Comment: I don't think there are directions, but basically, copy the web/app module in GeoServer (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/tree/master/src/web/app) , which is really just wiring up things toghether,  and customize its pom.xml to preserve the modules you want, and remove the ones you do not.